# How to determine if person is over 21 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view in MySQL. I want it to display the user email, first-lastname, their DOB, and their current age. I only want to show the users that are over 21 years of age.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE VIEW 'valid_Users' AS 
SELECT Persons.Email AS Email, Persons.FName + ' ' + Persons.LName AS Name,  Persons.DOB AS Birth_Date, DATEDIFF(Persons.DOB, NOW()) AS Current_Age'
FROM Persons
WHERE DATEDIFF(Persons.DOB, NOW()) > 21;
```

The issue is that the Where clause returns a negative number, which is obviously not a correct age. How would I edit this code to determine the proper age of a person?

I know the names aren't working - yet... but here is an image of the some current data. The actual table is 'Users'

[image]

Comment: Remove the single quotes.  *Only* use single quotes for string and date names.  In addition, your query would not work in MySQL anyway.  You seem rather confused.

Comment: When you run SELECT DATEDIFF(Persons.DOB, NOW()) AS days; what do you get?

Comment: Did you consider swapping the arguments to DATEDIFF? _...or looking at the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) on what values DATEDIFF returns?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE VIEW 'valid_Users' AS 
SELECT Persons.Email AS Email, Persons.FName + ' ' + Persons.LName AS Name, Persons.DOB AS Birth_Date, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Persons.DOB)), "%Y")+0 AS Current_Age'
FROM Persons
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Persons.DOB)), "%Y")+0 > 21;
```

OR:

```
CREATE VIEW 'valid_Users' AS 
SELECT Persons.Email AS Email, Persons.FName + ' ' + Persons.LName AS Name, Persons.DOB AS Birth_Date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Persons.DOB, NOW()) AS Current_Age'
FROM Persons
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Persons.DOB, NOW()) > 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW valid_Users AS 
    SELECT p.Email, 
           CONCAT(p.FName, ' ', p.LName) AS Name,  
           p.DOB AS BirthDate,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF('year', p.DOB, CURDATE()) AS CurrentAge
    FROM Persons p
    WHERE p.DOB < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 YEARS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try switching parameters:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), Persons.DOB) AS days;
```

tell us what do you get?